# Can i always resolve a recurrence of order 1 homogeneous with the following equivalence $a_n=k\cdot a_{n-1}\:\Rightarrow \:a_n=k^n\cdot a_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I want to resolve the following recurrence of order 1 homogeneous:

$a_n\:=\:4n\cdot \:a_{n-1}\:\:\:\:\:\forall n\:\ge 1\:\:and\:a_0\:=\:2$

Someone told me that the following property works for any recurrence of order 1 homogeneous.
$a_n=k\cdot a_{n-1}\:\Rightarrow \:a_n=k^n\cdot a_0$

I already used that equivalency in the following recurrences and it worked

- $a_n-5a_{n-1}\:=\:0\:\:\forall n\:\ge 1\:\:and\:a_0\:=\:1$

$a_n\:=\:\left(5\right)^n\:$

- $3a_n-5a_{n-1}\:=\:0\:\:\:and\:\:a_0\:=\:4$

$a_n\:=\:\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n\cdot 4\:\:$

Except this one $a_n\:=\:4n\cdot \:a_{n-1}\:\:\:\:\:\forall n\:\ge 1\:\:and\:a_0\:=\:2$

$a_n\:=\:2\:\cdot \:\left(4n\right)^n$

---

I have already found the correct solution that is $a_n\:=\:4^n\cdot \:\:n^{\underline{n}}$, but the unique way was writing $a_0\:,\:a_1\:,\:a_2,\:a_3\:\:$ to find the general term. I would like to know if the mentioned property $a_n=k\cdot a_{n-1}\:\Rightarrow \:a_n=k^n\cdot a_0$ can work with a modification for any recurrence with orden 1 homogeneous or for this recurrence $a_n\:=\:4n\cdot \:a_{n-1}\:\:\:\:\:\forall n\:\ge 1\:\:and\:a_0\:=\:2$

Comment: Unless I am misinterpreting your notation, I don't agree with your answer of $a_n=4^n\cdot n^{\underline{n}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're formula that $a_n=k\cdot a_{n-1}\implies a_n=k^n\cdot a_0$ only works when $k$ is a constant independent of $n$.

If instead, you have a function $f(n)$ with $a_n=f(n)\cdot a_{n-1}$. Then we have $a_n=a_0\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n f(i)$. This can easily be verified with induction.

So in your example, we have $a_0=2$ and $f(n)=4n$. Hence,
$$a_n=2\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n 4i$$
$$a_n=2\cdot 4^n\cdot n!$$

---

On a side note, if we have the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+f(n)$, then similarly we can inductively prove that $a_n=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$.

Comment: You can also substitute $n!=n^{\underline{n}}$ if you wanted to use the falling factorial notation.

Comment: By the given property $a_n=a_o\cdot \prod _{i=1}^nf\left(i\right)$, Do you mean $a_n=2\cdot \prod _{i=1}^n\left(4\cdot i\right)$?

Comment: @Metoballaes Yeah, sorry about that